# Why is data overriding in Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This may be a silly question but I can't understand why is this happening. I'm working in an Ionic app, and I have a controller which is injected with multiple services, these services are basically promises that make a http request to an API URL. That's working fine but I need to add another service and inject it to my controller, but when I do so all data loaded previously no longer appears.

I removed a function that uses another service and it works (and viceversa), but I need both services. It seems like something in scope is being overwritten but I can't get why is that happening. I wish you could help me here, guys.

This is the code of the controller. I'm not including services code 'cause that's fine. The service I want to use is **followService**, the one I removed for followService to work was **profileInformationService**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')

.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $controller, $state, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, store, userDataService, profileInformationService, feedService, followService){
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/post_detail.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal){
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $controller('utilsCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
  $scope.login_required = true;
  $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
  $scope.upload = {};
  $scope.profile = {followers: 0, following: 0};
  $scope.indicator = '';
  $scope.following = {};
  $scope.upload.profilePicture = null;
  $scope.charity = store.get('charity_name');
  $scope.refreshFeed = function(){
    userDataService.getUserData().then(function(user){
      $scope.user = user;
      console.log(user);
      $scope.wallet = store.get('wallet');
      feedService.getPosts($scope.user.username).then(
        function(response){
          //for (var item in response.data){
          //  response.data[item].total_description = response.data[item].description
          //  if (response.data[item].description.length > 50){
          //    response.data[item].description = response.data[item].description.substring(0, 47)+"..."
          //  }
          //};
          $scope.feed = organize_posts(response, 'peeks');
          // followService.getFollowingList().then(
          //   function (list) {
          //     console.log(list)
          //   },function(error){
          //     console.log("Re Paila")
          //   } 
          // );

          profileInformationService.getProfileInfo(user.username).then(
            function(data){
              $scope.profile = data.data;
              feedService.getKeeps().then(
                function(keeps){
                  //for (var item in keeps.data){
                  //  keeps.data[item].total_description = keeps.data[item].description
                  //  if (keeps.data[item].description.length > 50){
                  //    keeps.data[item].description = keeps.data[item].description.substring(0, 47)+"..."
                  //  }
                  //};
                  keeps = organize_posts(keeps, 'keeps');
                  //console.log(keeps)
                  $scope.feed.data = $scope.feed.data.concat(keeps.data);
                  console.log($scope.feed.data)
                });
            });
        }
        );
    }, function(error){
      $state.go('login');
    }).finally(function(){
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete'); 
    });
  };
  $scope.refreshFeed();



  organize_posts = function(items, variable){
  for (var item in items.data){
    if(variable == 'peeks'){
      items.data[item].peeks = true
    }else if(variable == 'keeps'){
      items.data[item].keeps = true
    }
    items.data[item].total_description = items.data[item].description
    if (items.data[item].description.length > 50){
      items.data[item].description = items.data[item].description.substring(0, 47)+"..."
    }
  };
  return items;
  }

  $scope.submit = function(){
    userDataService.updateUserData($scope.user).then(function(data){
      alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Success',
        template: 'User data was updated.'
      });
      $state.go('tabsController.profile');
    }, function(error){
      alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error',
        template: 'Data could not be updated.'
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.openFileDialog = function(){
    ionic.trigger('click', { target: document.getElementById('profile-picture') }); 
  };

  $scope.$watch("upload.profilePicture", function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue!=null && typeof newValue.name=='string'){
      userDataService.updateProfilePicture(newValue).then(
          function(response){
            user.profile_picture = response.data.success;
          });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you place a `debugger;` inside your `refreshFeed()` and step through the function?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, how does debugger works?

Comment: Put `debugger;` right before the point where you want the compiler to pause.  Pausing enables you to take a look at the content of all variables before functions are executed.  You'll need to have web developer console open.  There are various plugins and extensions you can download.